# Help to get some values from result

Tags: jquery, iteration, each

I have this code to get results based in search query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#envio').click(function(){
            var iURL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images";
            $.ajax({
                url: iURL,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    v:  '1.0',
                    q:  $('#query').val(),
                    format: 'json',
                    jsoncallback:  '?'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
                        html += '<img src="' + v.unescapedUrl + '" title="' + v.title + '" alt="' + v.title + '"/>';
                    });
                    $('body').append(html);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                    console.log(xhr.statusText, textStatus, error);
                }
            });               
        });
    });
```

This return a Object as you can see in images exposed at this URL: http://www.dropmocks.com/mZX1j. My question is how I can get unescapedUrl value for each result? The $.each in the code before doesn't work as you can see in images too. you can test it by yourself in this URL http://reyner.subdivx.com/prueba1.php and see the returned JSON or returned Object. Any help?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: A fiddle never hurts, as such: http://jsfiddle.net/73hnQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$.each(data.responseData.results, function(i, v) {
  ...
});
```

The 'results' seem to be nested a little deeper according to the console print out.

Comment: Exactly. If you dig a little deeper in Firebug, you have a very good visualization of the returned data.

Comment: I have another two question regardless this, the first go to pagination or to get more images instead than 4 by default? the second goes to get an alert when click in each image and get the title? I try with this code: $('img').click(function(){
                $.each(function(){
                    $('#urlimagen').val($this.src);
                });
            }); but didn't work, any help?